# Disabling a template class member function with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

Suppose I have a class that accepts some type `T`. This means it could accept some type `optional<U>`. I want to disable a function if it is not of an `optional` type, but if it is... then I want to know that type `U`.

I've been able to to disable the function via templates, but I don't know how to handle detecting a templated template class without writing the same class twice and making one a templated template version.

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41dfbeea013d8583):

```
class Dummy{};

template <typename T>
class C {
    T t;
    
public:
    C(T t) : t(std::move(t)) { }
    
    T get() {
        return t;
    }
    
    // Will clearly fail when T doesn't have a value_type
    template <typename R = T, typename OptT = typename T::value_type, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, optional<OptT>>>>
    std::vector<OptT> stuff() {
        std::vector<OptT> vec;
        // Do stuff, fill vec
        return vec;
    }
};

int main() {
    C<Dummy> c{Dummy()};                // Error
    // C<optional<Dummy>> c{Dummy()};   // Works fine
    c.get();
}
```

In doing this, I get

> main.cpp: In instantiation of 'class C':
>
> main.cpp:33:14:   required from here
>
> main.cpp:25:23: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'class Dummy'
>
> ```
>  std::vector<OptT> stuff() {
>
>                    ^~~~~
> ```

**Note**: It is okay if there is a specialization of this class, all I care about is detecting if its `std::optional`. I do not need it to work for any other type... only optional. This may allow for some kind of template specialization but I didn't figure out how to do that when researching it.

How can I make this function only appear when the type is `std::optional`, and then when it is that type, be able to grab the type inside the optional? Can I do this without touching the template definition of `T`? (as in, can I do it while leaving it as `template <typename T>` without changing it to `template <template <typename> T>` or having to copy this class where both the above are made)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here:

```
// Will clearly fail when T doesn't have a value_type
template <typename R = T,
          typename OptT = typename T::value_type,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, optional<OptT>>>>
```

Is that you introduced a new dummy template parameter, `R`, but you're still using the old one, `T`, for all your checks. So none of the checks are actually dependent. Swap them to `R` and you're fine.

---

A different approach would be to defer to a different function using just a tag parameter:

```
template <typename> struct tag { };

template <typename R=T>
auto stuff() -> decltype(stuff_impl(tag<R>{})) {
    return stuff_impl(tag<R>{});
}
```

Where now you can effectively just use normal template deduction to pull out the type:

```
template <typename U>
std::vector<U> stuff_impl(tag<std::optional<U>>) {
    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to define a custom type traits as follows

```
template <typename>
struct optionalType
 { };

template <typename T>
struct optionalType<std::optional<T>>
 { using type = T; };
```

that define `type` (the type `T` of the `std::optional<T>`) when and only when invoked with a `std::optional`.

Now your `stuff()` simply become

```
template <typename R = T,
          typename OptT = typename optionalType<R>::type>
std::vector<OptT> stuff() {
    std::vector<OptT> vec;
    // Do stuff, fill vec
    return vec;
}
```

Observe that `OptT`, the type of the `std::optional`, is present only when `R` (aka `T`) is a `std::optional`; you have a substitution failure, otherwise, that disable `stuff()`.

You can verify that

```
C<Dummy>                c0{Dummy()};
C<std::optional<Dummy>> c1{Dummy()};

//c0.stuff(); // compilation error
c1.stuff();   // compile
```